# Loop over list of objects skipped

Tags: c++, list, class

I'm making a list of Student Objects, and want to iterate over them and output the values they have. I'm not sure why the for loop is being skipped over. Any help/guidance would be appreciated. Here is the loop:

```
void studentInfo(list<Student> stuList) {
    cout << "in studentinfo" << endl;
    for (list<Student>::iterator it = stuList.begin(); it != stuList.end(); ++it) {
        cout << "in student info loop" << endl;
        cout << it->toString();
    }
    cout << "after loop" << endl;
}
```

I get the cout messages that are right before and after the loop. Here is the toString() method if you need.

```
string Student::toString() {
    stringstream outString;
    outString << "Name: " << name << "\nID: " << id << "\nAge: " << age << endl;
    return outString.str();
}
```

This is how the list is being populated, I'm adding 2 student objects usually when testing:

```
void addToList(list<Student> stuList) {
    string tempName;
    int tempID;
    int tempAge;
    int numStudents;

    cout << "How many students will you be entering?\n";
    cin >> numStudents;

    for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
        cout << "Enter student name: \n";
        cin >> tempName;
        cout << "Enter student id: \n";
        cin >> tempID;
        cout << "Enter student age: \n";
        cin >> tempAge;
        stuList.push_back(Student(tempName, tempID, tempAge));
    }
}
```

Comment: So what do you see when you use a debugger to step through the code?

Comment: Is the list empty?

Comment: Edited for how list is being populated.  I'm not sure how to use a debugger.  I'm using visual studio though if you have any resources for doing that.

Comment: your `addToList` only adds to a (function) local copy of the passed in `list`, not to the "original". Also searching for "visual studio debugging" brings you right to the official docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt.aspx

Comment: Also there's simple debugging using printing (e.g.: here `cout`) where you put outputs where you suspect/see a problem

Comment: Oh! Thank you, I was able to get it working after reading your comment. Will definitely read over the debugging documents.